# VSE : two scene camera strip alpha over not working

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, transparency

My scene is composed of two cameras. One camera points to an image plane and the other points to a Text object. In the VSE i added two scene strips
with each camera. I want the first strip i.e image one to be overlayed by the second one i.e text object one with the alpha. I set the text object strip blend option to alpha over but when i render the alpha channel is opaque. I would like the text object to overlay the image. Here are some pictures :
[image: Scene setup]

[image: VSE setup]

[image: Render alpha missing]

By the way some may wonder why he doesn't put the text object in front of the image plane, well this is because ultimately i want to create in the vse a slidehow with multiple image camera strips and one text camera strip that is in the foreground.

Thanks.

Comment: Under render tab -> film, make sure the transparent check box is checked. Ultimately I wouldn't recommend you to do this kind of job in blender, unless you're just testing blender's capability.

Comment: Thank you very much SVAFnemesis, it has worked. What would you recommend instead?

Comment: for professional choice of video editing, choose either adobe premiere or final cut. For casual fun project, I'm not sure. Perhaps someone else can fill in my blank.

Comment: In fact i am writing a python program that creates slideshow automatically that's why i am using blender.

Comment: Have a look at the Dynamic Slideshow addon for Blender that also uses multiple cameras and the VSE https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?360518-Addon-Dynamic-Slideshow